# Не работает условие if в js. Почему?

Tags: javascript

Завернул выполнение умножение в 3 условия. В зависимости от value select число должно умножаться на разные числа.
Но конструкция не работает. Выполняется только одно условие при value=1.

Что я сделал не так?

```js
let arg = document.querySelector('input[name="argument"]');
let res = document.querySelector('input[name="result"]');
let cur = document.querySelector('select');
let arr = [arg, cur];
if (cur.value=1)
{
  let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * 10;
  arr.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('input', calc);
  });
  calc();
}
else if (cur.value=2)
{
  let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * 5;
  arr.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('input', calc);
  });
  calc();
}
else if (cur.value=3)
{
  let calc = () => res.value = arg.value * 8;
  arr.forEach(function(el){
    el.addEventListener('input', calc);
  });
  calc();
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="argument" value="2"/>
<input type="text" name="result"/>
<select name="currency">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2" selected>2</option>
  <option value="3" >3</option>
</select>
```

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: проверка условия должна быть **внутри** обработчиков

Answer (score 3):

Для сравнение нужно использовать `==` или `===` для строгого сравнения.

`=` - это оператор присвоения значения

Более подробно можете почитать [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/comparison).

Должно быть так:

```
if (cur.value == 1) {

}
```

Comment: Это помогло, однако не решило полностью мою проблему. Срабатывает только первое условие if. При выборе других значений value в select результат не меняется.